# QPushButton FocusIn generates which signal?

Tags: python, qt, focus, pyqt, signals-slots

I am creating a small PyQt application and got stuck up in MouseOver effect.

I have a `QMainWindow` which has three buttons named `createProfileButton`, `downloadPackagesButton` and `installPackagesButton`. All these are of type `QPushButton`

Now I have created a Label which will hold the text when someone hovers the mouse over any of these button. I checked the documentation and came to know that it can be handled using over-riding

- focusInEvent(self, QFocusEvent)
- focusOutEvent(self, QFocusEvent)

methods of the button. Now this means that I have to extend `QPushButton` for each of the three buttons and each one of them have to an object for one class. I tried hunting for the signal which is emitted when mouse is hovered or taken away from the button, but in vain. All help I got on the net was to implement these two methods.

Isnt extending a class and creating one of each an overkill? A signal would be neat, unfortunately, I couldn't find any signal.

- http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpushbutton.html - Has no signals
- http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractbutton.html - Has clicked, released, pressed and toggled signals
- http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html - Has only one method

So I checked the whole inheritance hierarchy and found no signal for `FocusIn` and `FocusOut`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, no signals exist for this functionality.  You have two basic options.

**Option 1** - Subclass:

```
class FocusEmittingButton(QPushButton):
    #...
    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        # emit your signal
```

You can then connect to that signal in your client code.  Also, if necessary, you can use designer's `Promote To` feature to promote each button to the `FocusEmittingButton` type.  You'll only need to subclass once, and then make sure the different buttons are all of the same type.

**Option 2** - Use `QApplication.focusChanged`

You can also leverage `QApplication.focusChanged(oldQWidget, newQWidget)`.  By doing so, you won't need to subclass and override the focus events.  Instead, you connect to the `QApplication.focusChanged` signal and then respond in a handler.

Comment: I meant that this is the only way I could add Focus events. I again said that I wanted to use signals and not Event methods. I don't want to subclass one class for each button.

Comment: There is no signal for focus as you stated yourself, you have to either subclass QPushButton (once not one for each instance) to send a signal when it gets focus, or use QApplication.focusChanged as Kaleb said.

Comment: @Manish - I see what you're getting at.  I've edited my answer to clarify how you would subclass. If option 2 isn't clear enough, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Kaleb, now the explanation is more clear. I will try out and tell you in ASAP

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to receive focus signals in a parent widget. You can add an event filter:

```
class MyParent(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        self.mybutton.installEventFilter()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.mybutton and event.type() == QEvent.FocusOut:
           #...
        return QWidget.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```